# Точность при вычислении

Tags: c

Решаю олимпиадные задачи различного рода, когда работал в Паскале никогда и не задумывался над работой оператора"=" или ">=" в работе с вещественными числами, я думал, что с точностью сравнений и проблем не может быть. Но вот я перешел на C++ и один учитель мне сказал, что "==" или ">=" нельзя использовать при работе с вещественными числами в Си, нужно писать `fabs(a - b) > eps`. И вот вопрос:

1. Правда ли это?
2. Как правильно подобрать eps?
3. И почему же могли некоторые задачи не проходить все тесты с такой фишкой, а когда писал просто "==" они проходили.

Вот конкретный пример. Задача, которая прошла после того, как я изменил `LessEqual` на "<=". Дано действительное число a и натуральное n. Вычислите корень n-й степени из числа a. Программа должна вывести единственное число: ответ на задачу с точностью не менее 6 знаков после запятой

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
const double eps = 1e-8;
const double eps2 = 1e-12;

bool Equal(double a, double b)
{
    return fabs(a - b) < eps2;
}

bool lessEqual(double a, double b)
{
    return ((a < b) || Equal(a, b));
}

double a;
int n;

void solve()
{
    double l = 0,
           r = a + 1,
           mid = 0;
    while (r - l > eps)
    {
        mid = (l + r) / 2;
        if (lessEqual(pow(mid, n), a))
            l = mid;
        else
            r = mid;
    }
    printf("%.7lf", l);
}

int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    scanf("%lf\n", &a);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    solve();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не волнуйтесь, вы перешли на новый уровень сложности. скоро у вас будет level up :)

Comment: В Паскале правила игры точно такие же, т.к. все это рано или поздно упирается в IEEE754 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Действительно ничего хорошего из сравнения типа == при операциях с вещественными числами не выйдет. Можно попробовать простой код:

```
double sum = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i++; i < 1000000000 ) {
    sum += 0.000000001
}
```

Гарантировать, что в итоге sum будет равным 1 в данном случаи невозможно. Может быть равен, а может и нет. Дело в машинной точности округления мат. операций. И ваш преподаватель все правильно говорит. Сравнение вида

```
fabs ( 1.0 - sum ) < 0.0000000000000001;
```

Даст верный результат всегда. 
ps Число 0.0000000000000001 взял просто так, но поверьте, такая ошибка вычислений очень мала, но все же точного результата ( sum == 1.0 ) вы не получите

Answer (score 6):

Проблема здесь не в *"неточном"* сравнении аппаратурой процессора, а в том, что *некоторые* **десятичные дроби** не могут быть **точно преобразованы** в двоичный формат чисел с плавающей точкой.

Еще одна проблема заключается в потере младших разрядов мантиссы при вычислениях в циклах.

Answer (score 3):

1. В развитие ответа уважаемого [[@AVP](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp). Если задача позволяет, преобразуйте свои числа к дробям, которые могут быть представлены двоичной дробью: не 0.1, а, например, 25/256 и т.д. Это обезопасит Ваши циклы от недохода или превышения заданной величины постоянной цикла.
2. В С++ определена интересующая Вас константа epsilon в библиотеке float.h - DBL_EPSILON. Посмотрите ее значение именно для Вашего компилятора.
3. Сравнение ">=" - всегда правомерно.

Answer (score 1):

1. Не совсем верно.
2. eps зависит от того, насколько точно вы хотите посчитать те или иные показатели. Обычно точность указывается при постановке задачи. Например: Посчитать с точностью до седьмого знака после запятой, тогда eps = 0.0000001
3. Тут непонятно, нужно смотреть задачи.

А вообще, точность достаточно условное понятие, как можно видеть из формулы fabs(a - b) > eps, и от задаче к задаче она будет меняться.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, в реальной жизни нельзя, например, сказать что две палки равны по длине, можно сказать что их длины различаются на очень небольшую величину, т.е. |длина1-длина2|<eps. Поскольку числа с плавающей точкой используются для моделирования реальных ("вещественных") величин, то и обращаться с ними нужно соответственно.

К вопросу, как подобрать eps. Для палок может быть достаточно 1 см, для каких-то деталей - 0.5 мм. А если в задании сказано, например, посчитать с точностью до 6 знака после запятой, то eps принимаем равным 1E-6 (т.е. 10 в -6 степени).

Comment: Не совсем так. Если два числа с плавающей точкой получены *одними и теми же* вычислениями (последовательностью команд с одинаковыми начальными данными), то они будут **равны**. 

Если вычислять их "несколько разными" алгоритмами, то могут различаться.

Comment: [Кроме случая, если эти числа были получены одними и теми же вычислениями на процессорах пентиум][1]

[1]:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug

Comment: @avp, да, технически могут быть равны, но на практике совпадение вещественных чисел до последнего двоичного знака после запятой обычно не требуется.